# Почему Курсор не меняется в клиенте RDP remmina?

Tags: linux-mint, rdp, linux

В клиенте RDP remmina в Linux Mint 14 MATE после подключения к удаленному рабочему столу при перемещении мыши курсор все время имеет вид стрелки, а не меняется как на простом экране. В чем дело? И можете ли порекомендовать другой клиент?

Answer (score 2):

Дело в самом клиенте. Вот что пишут на Ланчпаде: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/remmina/+bug/944548 **Вот это вам поможет:** https://code.launchpad.net/~freerdp-team/+archive/freerdp А вот тут коммент по поводу исправления: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/remmina/+bug/944548/comments/16

Comment: Спасибо! Буду использовать! Для плюсов - балов не хватает :(

Comment: apt-get -f install - не помогает!!!

Comment: Надо репозиторий добавить:sudo add-apt-repository ppa:freerdp-team/freerdpПотом сделать sudo apt-get updateИ потом только устанавливать! Кстати, можно и без -f